# Toggle going wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made some menu with a slide down submenu. It should work fine but for some reason it doesn't work. I mean if you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yJdFu/2/ , you'll see that the big menus don't slide down when the submenu toogles.

Can you tell me why isn't it working ?

Comment: you should have a look at jQueryUI accordion. It will do the job for you. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: For the content I load I'm using jquery tools. But what I'm interested in is the left side menu, which doesn't work as it should. I have the same thing somewhere else and it works fine. That's why I asked, to see why it doesn't.

Comment: I think there's something in your CSS that's causing the problem. I couldn't see the specific problem, but if you delete all the CSS it looks ugly but the slide function works the way you would expect. So I'd suggest you start with a blank CSS slate and try adding back your original styles a little bit at a time until it breaks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually working. The problem is you have a specified height to the list items. So the submenu is appearing below the existing items.

Remove the height from the list items.
[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/yJdFu/5/)

You weren't missing any closing tags. The html is correct. Error was in CSS. Also, I altered the jquery a bit. not sure why you were using .find() when the item can be called by it's class, and I specified which toggle to use.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/yJdFu/6/) uses jquery which specifies the toggle only occurs on the "dashboard" link. Otherwise the sub navigation closes when one of its links is clicked.

Comment: OK. But see that when you click on a sublist item it also slides back, I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</li>` tag.

```
<li class="dashboard"><a href="#">
  <img src="assets/gfx/dashboard.png" alt="Dashboard">
  <span>Dashboard</span></a>
</li>
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/yJdFu/4/

As Roland said above, you may also want to look at the built-in [JQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) before rolling your own solution.

Comment: Yes, but, when you want to click on it again to toogle it back it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Also, I cannot use accordion because I will load content with ajax, and jQuery Tools offers me that option, UI doesn't, and if I want to do it with UI it would be complicated loading content with ajax. So that is why I opted for jQuery Tools, but in this situation, that solution might not work too, so I'll have to think about it.

Comment: There is no missing `</li>` You introduced an extra one.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to clear up the spare one. It does fix the slideout though but it sounds like this isn't the structure the OP wants.